# create branch from origin/14.4_dev but do NOT track remote

Tags: git, github

I am trying to come up with a strategy to give to my developers on how to create branches and pull requests. The developers each have a form of the main repository.

Basically our main branch is 14.4_dev and I want them to start all their work from the 14.4_dev branch.

I have the main trunk of development (remote blasto333).

So I have them do:

```
git remote add blasto333 git@github.com:PHP-Point-Of-Sale/PHP-Point-Of-Sale.git;
git fetch blasto333;
git checkout blasto333/14.4_dev -b MY_NEW_FEATURE
```

The problem is the remote from the branch is blasto333/14.4_dev when I would want them to have the remote be their origin/NEW_FEATURE_NAME.

How can I create a simple process for this?

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the origin name from the to-be-branched-off branch

```
git checkout 14.4_dev -b MY_NEW_FEATURE
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, the above will only work if the remote branch is already locally checked out.

The following will allow to check out the branch without the tracking branch. The downside is that on the first push the remote tracking branch needs to be specified explicitely.

```
git checkout blasto333/14.4_dev -b MY_NEW_FEATURE --no-track
```

On their first push, the developers can specify their own remote tracking branch

```
git push origin -u MY_NEW_FEATURE
```